# CGImageSource to CGImage?

Tags: swift, xcode, cgimage, cgimageref, cgimagesource

I got this following code that access a PHAsset.  I need to pass a CGImage out of this:

```
let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
imageManager.requestImageDataForAsset(self.asset!, options: nil, resultHandler:{
    (data, responseString, imageOriet, info) -> Void in
    let imageData: NSData = data!
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil) {
        let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary

        //How do I create a CGImage now?

    }
})
```

I need to extract a CGImage out of this.  Having trouble getting there...

Comment: Do you require a `CGImageRef` specifically or would an `NSImage` work?  Have you tried `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`?

Comment: Got it to work with CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you have the image source you can create an image using `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`:

```
let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
```